Stable diffusion three no unet being passed
Hi I am trying to use stable diffusion three when using the StableDiffusionPipeline but get the error of.
It is missing the unet attribute
Pipeline <class 'diffusers.pipelines.stable_diffusion.pipeline_stable_diffusion.StableDiffusionPipeline'> expected {'unet', 'feature_extractor', 'text_encoder', 'image_encoder', 'tokenizer', 'scheduler', 'vae', 'safety_checker'}, but only {'tokenizer', 'text_encoder', 'scheduler', 'vae'} were passed.

I am using "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3-medium" from hugging face
I have tried using the StableDiffusion3Pipeline but that also does not work as there is not unet attribute which i need for sample size and to get cross attention. Is there any help available?
Thanks
This is the python code that loads it
model = StableDiffusionPipeline("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3-medium", revision="refs/pr/26", torch_dtype=torch.float16)

This is the stable diffusion three pipeline error
AttributeError: 'StableDiffusion3Pipeline' object has no attribute 'unet'

